# How to add layer name in the output of freq function using terra package?

Tags: r, terra

I want to add the layer name in place of layer number in the output of `freq` function using `terra` r package. Here is a reproducible example

```
library(terra)

# first create a raster
r1 <- r2 <- r3 <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10)
# Assign random cell values
values(r1) <- runif(ncell(r1))
values(r2) <- runif(ncell(r2))
values(r3) <- runif(ncell(r3))
s <- c(r1, r2, r3)
names(s) <- c("a", "b", "c")
# classify the values into four groups
m <- c(0, 0.1, 1,
       0.1, 0.3, 2,
       0.3, 0.6, 3,
       0.6, 1, 4)

#Reclassify the raster stack
rclmat <- matrix(m, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
rc1 <- classify(s, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE)

#Calculate frequency of pixels under each class
(f <- freq(rc1))

#>     layer value count
#> [1,]     1     1     5
#> [2,]     1     2    24
#> [3,]     1     3    32
#> [4,]     1     4    39
#> [5,]     2     1     9
#> [6,]     2     2    27
#> [7,]     2     3    32
#> [8,]     2     4    32
#> [9,]     3     1     6
#> [10,]     3     2    20
#> [11,]     3     3    34
#> [12,]     3     4    40
```

As you can see from the output layer represents the layer number. Now how to add layer name in the output of `freq` function using terra package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
set.seed(2)
values(r) <- sample(5, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
x <- c(r, r/3)
names(x) <- c("a", "b")
```

Solution

```
f <- freq(x)
f <- data.frame(f)
f$layer <- names(x)[f$layer]
f
#  layer value count
#1     a     1    27
#2     a     2    15
#3     a     3    17
#4     a     4    17
#5     a     5    24
#6     b     0    27
#7     b     1    49
#8     b     2    24
```

You can also get the same result in one step with

```
freq(x, usenames=TRUE)
```